# 'The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable' : Bubble Sort - JAVA OOP

Tags: java, oop, variables, variable-assignment, bubble-sort

I have this function which runs a Bubble Sort algorithm to sort a LinkedList created in another class.

```
for(int k=0; k < n; k++){  
                for(int j=1; j < (n-i); j++){  
                         if(loopObj.loopedGradeReq(j-1) > loopObj.loopedGradeReq(j)){  
                                //swap elements  
                                temp = loopObj.loopedGradeReq(j-1);  
                                loopObj.getGradeReq().get(j-1) = loopObj.getGradeReq().get(j);
                                arr[j-1] = arr[j];  
                                loopObj.getGradeReq().get(j) = temp;  
                        }  

                }  
        }
```

However, I keep getting a

> 'the left hand side of an argument must be a variable'

error whenever I get to this line :

```
 loopObj.getGradeReq().get(j-1) = loopObj.getGradeReq().get(j);
```

What can I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Both sides of the assignment return a value, that is to say that you are calling the get() function of the GradeReq returned by loopObj.getGradeReq(). You can't assign to the value returned by a function (get()), rather you do something with it. Without seeing the interfaces there's not enough information to completely answer this, but the solution might look something more like...

```
loopObj.getGradeReq().set(j-1, loopObj.getGradeReq().get(j));
```

assuming that there was a method called set(index, object) in the GradeReq class.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you, i'll give it a try!